# sort visualizer bug in c++ using quicksort

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

so when I create this sorting visualiser using a game making library called splashkit, ( I know its not ideal but its what my course is teaching me in) I am trying to show the entire array and show each individual swap. But instead it is doing this: [Video of my bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpMX8jESoWI&feature=youtu.be)

I am not making sense of the logic of my code as I followed a tutorial to achieve this. The sort itself is fine and works great however the drawing of the rectangles is weird, and not what im trying to achieve.
[I would like to achieve something like this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L4Zb_DFzd8) (Without the colors/sound effects).
CODE UPDATED:

```
#include "splashkit.h"

#define NUM_VALS 200

void draw_values(const int values[], int size)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y;
    int rect_height;
    int rect_width = screen_width() / size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        rect_height = values[i];
        y = screen_height() - rect_height;

        fill_rectangle(COLOR_RED, x, y, rect_width, rect_height);
        draw_rectangle(COLOR_WHITE, x, y, rect_width, rect_height);

        x += rect_width;
    }
}

void draw_sort(int values[], int size)
{
    clear_screen(COLOR_WHITE);
    draw_values(values, size);
    refresh_screen(60);
}

void swap (int &value1, int &value2)
{
    int temp = value1;
    value1 = value2;
    value2 = temp;
}

/* inspiration/educated from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/ */
int partition (int values[], int low, int size)
{
    int pivot = values[size]; // the pivot value
    int i = (low - 1); // currently selected element

    // work out if all values have become the pivot value, loop until all have.
    for (int j = low; j <= size-1; j++)
    {
        if (values[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(values[i], values[j]);
            draw_sort(values, size);
        }
    }
    swap(values[i + 1], values[size]);
    draw_sort(values, size);
    return (i+1);
}

void quick_sort (int values[], int low, int size)
{
    if (low < size)
    {
        // This is the partitioning index for quick sorting
        int pi = partition(values, low, size);

        // This sorts small partitions at a time then sorts them together.
        quick_sort(values, low, (pi - 1));
        quick_sort(values, (pi + 1), size);
    }
}

void bubble_sort(int values[], int size)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            if (values[i] > values[i + 1])
            {
                swap(values[i], values[i + 1]);
                draw_sort(values, size);
            }
        }
    }
}

void random_fill_array(int values[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        values[i] = rnd(screen_height()) + 1;
    }
}

void handle_input(int values[], int size)
{
    if (key_typed(R_KEY))
    {
        random_fill_array(values, size);
    }
    else if (key_typed(S_KEY))
    {
        bubble_sort(values, size);
    }
    else if (key_typed(D_KEY))
    {
        quick_sort(values, 0, size);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int values[NUM_VALS];

    open_window("Sort Visualiser", 800, 600);

    random_fill_array(values, NUM_VALS);

    while ( not quit_requested() )
    {
        process_events();
        handle_input(values, NUM_VALS);

        draw_sort(values, NUM_VALS);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to "draw" your swaps too if you want the same effect.

Comment: @SamerTufail Sorry I copied and pasted this without showing that i used draw_sort after all swap()'s. But that still doesnt fix this logic flaw.

Comment: you mean for each swap you called draw and that did not fix it?

Comment: @SamerTufail does this (editted this into post, and also updated my code to what it is now.)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpMX8jESoWI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It looks like your sorting has a "sliding window" effect, only sorting the elements within a given size block, rather than from the entire array of numbers.  Posting a video of the problem is a great idea, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the `quick_sort` function, `size` is not the size of the list its the size of the current partition, therefore you only draw the current partition not the whole list when you call `draw_sort`. You need to add extra parameters with the original list size:

```
int partition (int values[], int low, int partitionSize, int size)
{
    int pivot = values[partitionSize]; // the pivot value
    int i = (low - 1); // currently selected element

    // work out if all values have become the pivot value, loop until all have.
    for (int j = low; j <= partitionSize-1; j++)
    {
        if (values[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(values[i], values[j]);
            draw_sort(values, size);
        }
    }
    swap(values[i + 1], values[partitionSize]);
    draw_sort(values, size);
    return (i+1);
}

void quick_sort (int values[], int low, int partitionSize, int size)
{
    if (low < partitionSize)
    {
        // This is the partitioning index for quick sorting
        int pi = partition(values, low, partitionSize, size);

        // This sorts small partitions at a time then sorts them together.
        quick_sort(values, low, (pi - 1), size);
        quick_sort(values, (pi + 1), partitionSize, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, upon using your code to test however, I found that it only works if partitionSize and size are the same int?

This may be due to the program freezing im not sure. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @TrentBartels you'll have to debug that yourself I'm afraid, I didn't test the above code so may have made some mistakes (or it could be exposing bugs in your original code).

Comment: @TrentBartels do you mean the initial values you pass into your first call to `quick_sort`? If so yes, you must pass `size` for both values.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. It worked perfectly thank you!